# mpdf: Get the PDF file URL?

Tags: mpdf

With [mpdf](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf), the following outputs the PDF inline to the browser:

```
$mpdf->Output();
```

How can I simply get the full URL of the created file? For example:

```
// http://example.com/tmp/file.pdf
$url = $mpdf->getURL();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When outputting the file to the browser, the output file name *is* the file name of your script, no physical PDF file is being created and saved anywhere.

Therefore you could use something like

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

as answered in [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php).

Note that this cannot be used when you rely on HTTP POST method to generate the PDF.

---

If you need to save and provide static pdf file for later download, use `F` (or helper constant `\Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE` in mPDF 7.x) output mode with path to desired file in the `Output` method:

```
$filename = __DIR__ . '/download.pdf';
$mpdf->Output($filename, 'F');
```

You then have to create the URL to the file yourself as mPDF does not know anything (or care) about your domain, document root and path to the file-to-be-downloaded.

Also see [documentation on the `Output` method](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html).

Comment: Are you saying that no PDF file is actually generated on the server? I need to send the PDF file through a different script via the full URL; is this possible using *mpdf*? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Maybe this should be a feature request. It would be good to know whether if the output was successful, something like `$boolean = $mpdf->Output($filename, 'F');` with true and false.

Comment: If you don't get an error/exception from the Output method, the output was successful.

Comment: On this page: https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html You are missing a `>` in `'fontdata' = [`... Just bringing it to your attention. Thanks!

Comment: @HenrikPetterson please, do not pollute comments here with off-topic additions. There is a dedicated issue section for the documentation. https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf.github.io/issues